# pbm with query for wall messages order

Tags: mysql, message

I have a problem with a mysql query to order the message of a wall messages like facebook or other social sites...
I need to order my main messages in an descendant way and the secondary messages (the answers) in ascendant order...
So I made one table with the message_id, the message_target_id and the level of message (which is if it s an answer or not)...
The message_target_id is the order to take when i answer to a main message then i take this to put in the list of messages.

So here is my query...

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablemessages 
WHERE (message_user_id = '" .$_SESSION['id']."' ) 
ORDER BY IF (message_level = 0, message_id, message_target_id) DESC
```

But I'd to have something like this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablemessages 
WHERE (message_user_id = '" .$_SESSION['id']."' ) 
ORDER BY IF (message_level = 0, message_id, GROUP BY message_target_id ORDER BY ASC) DESC
```

(But I don't know how to express it in a correct query)
Thank you very much for you help,
Nono.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much to complete your `ORDER BY`:

```sql
ORDER BY IF(message_level = 0, message_id, message_target_id) DESC, message_id ASC
```

The problem is - it doesn't make sence in your query. You are selecting messages (main and secondary) from one user, but not the replies from other users.

What you probably need is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tablemessages
WHERE (message_level = 0 AND message_user_id = {$_SESSION['id']})
  OR  (message_level = 1 AND message_target_id IN (
    SELECT message_id 
    FROM tablemessages
    WHERE message_user_id = {$_SESSION['id']} AND message_level = 0
  ))
ORDER BY IF(message_level = 0, message_id, message_target_id) DESC, message_id ASC
```

This way you get all main messages from the logged in user and all replies on them.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3172e/2)

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you very much, but If i respond to my own messages as second response of my first response, I don't see them in the list...

Comment: You can respond on a response? That of course would make things much more complicated :-) - You either add a new column like `root_message_id` (id of the main message). Or you need to emplement some kind of complex tree structure.

Comment: Hoo... Ok cool, I'm going to try that... Thank you very much for all your help... Cheers.